# An less commonly seen sufficient condition for convexity

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

I was reading a proof in which the author claimed that, for a function $f(x)$ on $(0,1)$ which is continuous and strictly increasing, the following condition implies that convexity holds.

Let $A > B \geq C > D$ and $A - B = C- D$. Then $f(A) - f(B) \geq f(C) - f(D)$.

Pictorially it makes intuitive sense to me that the above condition would imply convexity, but is there a formal proof of this? Conversely, if $f(A) - f(B) \leq f(C) - f(D)$, would that imply concavity of $f$? My intuition is yes, though would like to double check.

Edit: Answered my own question, let B = C = (A + D)/2 to obtain midpoint convexity.

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a formal proof of this somewhere..?

Comment: I don't have a reference at the moment but it is folklore and I use it all the time.

Comment: I just thought of the proof, thanks

Comment: By the way, the strictly increasing hypothesis is unnecessary.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable one directly gets that the derivative is monotone non-decreasing by dividing both sides of the condition by $A - B = C- D$ and passing to the limit.